# Get response rest web services Using Java for Android

Tags: java, android, eclipse

the following code I produced following a tutorial on web services, but nothing is happening although no error is given. Can anyone help me please? as I cannot continue. I need to connect to a web service and this is not working.

Using the debugger i found out that it is stopping in the first method on this particular line: HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);

```
private String result = "";

 public void getResponse()
    {
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();    
        String query ="working url";

        try
        {
            URL url = new URL(query);
            URI uri = new URI(url.getProtocol(), url.getHost(),url.getPath(), url.getQuery(),null);
            HttpGet request = new HttpGet(uri);
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
            result=Userrequest(response); 

        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {

        }




    }
    public String Userrequest(HttpResponse response)
    {
        try     
        {
            InputStream in = response.getEntity().getContent();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
            StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
                    {
                        str.append(line + "\n");
                    }
            in.close();
            result = str.toString();
            updateData(result);         
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            //responsetxt.setText(ex.getMessage());
        }
        return result;
    }
    public void updateData(String result)
    {
        try     
        {
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(result);
            JSONArray ja;
            json = json.getJSONObject("responseData");
            ja = json.getJSONArray("results");

            int resultCount = ja.length();

            for (int i =0; i<resultCount; i++)
            {
                JSONObject resultObject = ja.getJSONObject(i);
                result = resultObject.toString();

            }

        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            //responsetxt.setText(ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you added internet permission in AndroidManifest.xml? Can you post your LogCat?

Comment: Thank you sooo much for your reply. No I did not add anything in my Manifest. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: `String result = EntityUtils.toString(response);` simplifies what you wrote (reading data from response buffer and creating a string).

Answer (score 0):

Add the string

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
```

In your AndroidManifest.xml, after the line

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="#" />
```

Where `#` represents you minSdkVersion

EDIT: try to change this:

```
        URL url = new URL(query);
        URI uri = new URI(url.getProtocol(), url.getHost(),url.getPath(), url.getQuery(),null);
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet(uri);
```

with this:

```
        URI uri = new URI(query);
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet();
        request.setUri(uri);
```

Comment: I added this but still nothing happens. :(

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" />
    
    <uses-permission  android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

Comment: In the error log, I have an Unhandled event loop exception, 


Error
Wed Nov 02 09:59:14 CET 2011
Unhandled event loop exception

org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: Failed to execute runnable (java.lang.NullPointerException)
 at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4282)
 at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4197)
 at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:138)
 at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:4140)
 at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3757)
 at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runEventLoop(Workbenc .....

Comment: Using the debugger i found out that it is stopping in the first method on this particular line: HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);

Comment: See the EDIT part in my answer